# Deterministic finite automaton in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, state-machine

Formally, a [deterministic finite automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) is a 5-tuple \$M = (Q, \Sigma, \delta, q_0, F)\$, where

- \$Q\$ is the set of all possible states
- \$\Sigma\$ is the alphabet
- \$\delta \colon Q \times \Sigma \to Q\$ is the transition function
- \$q_0\$ is the starting state
- \$F\$ is the set of accepting states

Basically, each DFA represents a so-called regular language \$L\$, and given input string \$s\$, answers whether \$s \in L\$. This is done in \$\mathcal{O}(|s|)\$ time simply by consuming each character and making the state transitions starting from \$q_0\$; if after reading the entire string we end up in a state in \$F\$, the DFA accepts the string.

Please, tell me anything that comes to mind.

**TransitionFunction.java**

```
package net.coderodde.dfa;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * This class implements a transition function.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Apr 2, 2016)
 */
public class TransitionFunction {

    private final Map<Integer, Map<Character, Integer>> function = 
          new HashMap<>();

    public void setTransition(Integer startState, 
                              Integer goalState,
                              char character) {
        function.putIfAbsent(startState, new HashMap<>());
        function.get(startState).put(character, goalState);
    }

    public Integer process(Integer startState, char character) {
        if (!function.containsKey(startState)) {
            return null;
        }

        return function.get(startState).get(character);
    }
}
```

**DFA.java**

```
package net.coderodde.dfa;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * This class implements a 
 * <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton">
 * deterministic finite automaton</a>.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Apr 2, 2016)
 */
public class DFA {

    private final TransitionFunction transitionFunction;
    private final int startState;
    private final Set<Integer> acceptingStates;

    public DFA(TransitionFunction transitionFunction,
               int startState,
               Set<Integer> acceptingStates) {
        this.transitionFunction = 
                Objects.requireNonNull(transitionFunction,
                                       "Transition function is null.");
        this.startState = startState;
        this.acceptingStates = 
                Objects.requireNonNull(acceptingStates,
                                       "Accepting state set is null.");
    }

    public boolean matches(String text) {
        Integer currentState = startState;

        for (char c : text.toCharArray()) {
            currentState = transitionFunction.process(currentState, c);

            if (currentState == null) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return acceptingStates.contains(currentState);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // A regular language over binary strings with even number of 1's.
        TransitionFunction transitionFunction = new TransitionFunction();

        transitionFunction.setTransition(0, 0, '0');
        transitionFunction.setTransition(1, 1, '0');
        transitionFunction.setTransition(0, 1, '1');
        transitionFunction.setTransition(1, 0, '1');

        Set<Integer> acceptingStates = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(0));
        DFA dfa = new DFA(transitionFunction, 0, acceptingStates);

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();

            if (line.trim().equals("end")) {
                break;
            }

            System.out.println(dfa.matches(line));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Java 8 constructs

The following

```
function.putIfAbsent(startState, new HashMap<>());
function.get(startState).put(character, goalState);
```

can be simplified by using the [`computeIfAbsent(key, mappingFunction)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) method. This method will return the current value associated with the given key or compute a new value for that key and return it. As such, you could have:

```
function.computeIfAbsent(startState, k -> new HashMap<>()).put(character, goalState);
```

Also, the following

```
if (!function.containsKey(startState)) {
    return null;
}
return function.get(startState).get(character);
```

can be also written more simply with the [`getOrDefault(key, defaultValue)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-) method. This will return the value associated with the given key or else return the default value. You could have:

```
return function.getOrDefault(startState, Collections.emptyMap()).get(character);
```

When the map doesn't contain the key `startState`, an empty map (that was already instantiated, it is a cached value) is returned with [`Collections.emptyMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#emptyMap--).

#### Code structure

You currently have a class `TransitionFunction` that holds all transitions and offers a method to go from one state to another for a particular character.

I find the name `TransitionFunction` a bit misleading because it would imply that the class is in fact a `Function` in that it is a functional interface taking a parameter and returing a value. But it is more than that since it is the class that holds all possible transitions.

Why not rename the class `Transitions` and:

- Rename the method `setTransition` to `addTransition` to better reflect the fact that this method adds a transition (instead of setting it).
- Move the code for processing all transitions, that is currently placed inside the `matches` method, in this class. This method would be called `processAll(Integer startState, char[] characters)` and would process all the characters given starting at the given state.

This is what the class could look like

```
public class Transitions {

    private final Map<Integer, Map<Character, Integer>> function = new HashMap<>();

    public void addTransition(Integer startState, Integer goalState, char character) {
        function.computeIfAbsent(startState, k -> new HashMap<>()).put(character, goalState);
    }

    public Integer process(Integer startState, char character) {
        return function.getOrDefault(startState, Collections.emptyMap()).get(character);
    }

    public Integer processAll(Integer startState, char[] characters) {
        return IntStream.range(0, characters.length)
                        .boxed()
                        .reduce(startState, (s, i) -> s == null ? null : process(s, characters[i]));
    }

}
```

Notice that the `processAll` method leverages an `IntStream` over the indexes of the input array. The final state is calculating by reducing from the starting state and calling `process` each time on the accumulated result. The difference between your initial code is that it is not short-circuiting; if you wish to keep that, you can keep your `for` loop as-is.

With this change, the `matches` method would just be:

```
public boolean matches(String text) {
    Integer finalState = transitionFunction.processAll(startState, text.toCharArray());
    return finalState != null && acceptingStates.contains(finalState);
}
```

#### Using [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html)

You are currently relying on `null` values to mean "no state". Using an `Optional` would remove all that. We could make the methods `process` and `processAll` return an `Optional<Integer>` with

```
public Optional<Integer> process(Integer startState, char character) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(function.getOrDefault(startState, Collections.emptyMap()).get(character));
}

public Optional<Integer> processAll(Integer startState, char[] characters) {
    return IntStream.range(0, characters.length)
                    .boxed()
                    .reduce(
                      Optional.of(startState),
                      (o, i) -> o.flatMap(s -> process(s, characters[i])),
                      (o1, o2) -> o1.map(Optional::of).orElse(o2)
                    );
}
```

`process` makes a call to [`Optional.ofNullable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ofNullable-T-) to wrap the value. The reducing part works on the optional values. The combiners [combines two optional into a single one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32776923/1743880).

Then, the `matches` method becomes

```
public boolean matches(String text) {
    return transitionFunction.processAll(startState, text.toCharArray())
                             .map(acceptingStates::contains)
                             .orElse(false);
}
```